# Кнопки появляются в одном и том же месте

Tags: android, android-button

У меня есть две кнопки, которые при появлении должны идти друг за другом в столбик с небольшим отступом. Но они просто накладываются друг на друга, и margin на них никак не влияет.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void potatoFunc() {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.product);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (event.getRawX() + dX != 15) {
                    String s = "Alex";
                } else {
                    Intent int46 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, potato.class);
                    startActivity(int46);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        dX = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX > 100){
                            view.setX(100);
                        }
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX < 15){
                            view.setX(15);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });



    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();
}


private void ogyrecFunc() {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageButton imageView1 = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct);
    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams1.setMargins(15,10,0,0);


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 26);
    editor.apply();

    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int461 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, ogyrec.class);
            startActivity(int461);
        }
    });


    mainLayout.addView(imageView1);

}

private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Если будут вопросы, обязательно задавайте.

Comment: вам нужно использовать `LinearLayout` вместо `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Jarvis_J Хорошо, сейчас переделаю и скажу результат.

Comment: еще совет по коду: у вас две практически идентичные функции. Лучше сделать одну, которая будет принимать аргумент и в зависимости от его значения выполнять различающийся код

Comment: @Jarvis_J Можете, пожалуйста подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: если вкратце, то так: `private void myFunc(int type) { if (type == POTATO) do 1; } else {do 2; }` дублирующий код написать вне условия. Вызывать: `myFunct(POTATO);`

Comment: @Jarvis_J Преобразование в LinearLayout не помогло

Comment: @Jarvis_J Я отредактирую свой вопрос, потому что в коде есть некоторые нюансы.

Comment: @Jarvis_J Не понимаю, почему кнопки находятся в одном и том же месте?

Comment: если у вас `R.id.mainmain` тоже `LinearLayout` всё должно работать. Попробуйте убрать лишнее в коде и запустить, постепенно добавляя строки, чтобы найти в чем проблема. По идее - использование `LinearLayout` решает проблему. В нем невозможно размещение разных элементов в одном и том же месте

Comment: @Jarvis_J Хорошо

Comment: @Jarvis_J По непонятной мне причине, кнопки опять появляются в одном и том же месте

Comment: @Jarvis_J Может я как-то ограничиваю мой LinearLayout, и сам этого не замечаю?

Comment: @Jarvis_J Добавлю код из разметки

Comment: @Jarvis_J Решил проблему. Добавил android:orientation="vertical" к LinearLayout

Comment: @Jarvis_J У меня есть к вам вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84084/discussion-between--and-jarvis-j).

Answer (score 1):

К LinearLayout добавил android:orientation="vertical"